# Playframework - API to check if Http context is available

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1

Many play API's give runtime exception 'There is no HTTP Context available from here.'. For e.g. usage of following code in playtemplate can give this runtime exception.

```
flash().remove("message")
```

Till now to solve this problem, I am using try/catch blocks and eat the exception in-case http context is not available, but I would rather check if http context is available or not instead of eating exception, so is there any API which allows the user to check presence of http context?
I have tried following but it also ended with runtime exception

```
@if(Http.Context.current() != null) {
       @* Do something here which needs http context *@
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code can be used to test the presence of context.

```
    if (Context.current.get() != null) {
        System.out.println("Context present");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No context");
    }
```

Hope this helps.